# Creating a Search Interface -Android

Tags: android

I am having trouble following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#TheBasicst) .  I am new to `Android Development` and have spent hours trying to create a `simple search function`. If I am just using a `search widget` function do I just need to `add` and `edit` the widget through the `activity_main.xml` and configure the Java in the `Main activity`?

I understand from the tutorial that I need the following:

1. A searchable configuration (This would be the manifest file?)
2. A searchable activity (This would be the searchable.xml listed in a xml folder?)
3. A search interface (This would be my search widget?)

If you're developing your application for Android 3.0 and have decided to use the search widget, **we recommend that you insert the search widget as an action view in the app bar, instead of using the search dialog** . (Does this mean that I don't make a search-view widget and make an "action view?")

Configuring the search widget
After you've created a **searchable configuration** and a **searchable activity** , as discussed above, you need to enable assisted search for each Search View.(In order to get a working search widget, I need the above listed searchable configuration and searchable activity?)

Comment: please post your code and what you're struggling with specifically

Comment: I am struggling with interpreting the documents and I am trying to figure out what I need to do to implement a simple search function. I did not post any type of code due to not knowing how to interpret the documents and lack of experience.

Comment: you'll find more help by doing something and trying something out first, maybe try finding a different tutorial, at the moment your question is quite broad. try adding in the content from the tutorial you don't understand and ask people to explain the content

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this below:

//In Xml

```
<ListView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:id="@+id/lv1"  
    android:divider="#ad5"  
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"  
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"/>  

<SearchView  
    android:id="@+id/searchView"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:queryHint="Search Here"  
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

//In Activity:

```
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);  
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);  

    list = new ArrayList<>();  
    list.add("Apple");  
    list.add("Banana");  
    list.add("Pineapple");  
    list.add("Orange");  
    list.add("Lychee");  
    list.add("Gavava");  
    list.add("Peech");  
    list.add("Melon");  
    list.add("Watermelon");  
    list.add("Papaya");  

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);  
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);  

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {  

            if(list.contains(query)){  
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);  
            }else{  
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Match found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }  
            return false;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {  
        //    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);  
            return false;  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Comment: You should mention the source :) https://www.javatpoint.com/android-searchview

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                userAddapter.setUserDataList(filter(newText));
                userAddapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                return false;
            }
        }
```

**filter query**

```
 public List filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
      List   filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

       if (charText.length() == 0) {
                    filteredList .addAll(list);
                } else {


                    for (String model : list) {
                        if (model.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                            filteredList.add(model);
                        }
                    }

                }

                return filteredList;
        }
```